# How to avoid getting different results in exponential and trigonometric forms

Tags: numerics

I have a complicated numerical complex expression which depends on 6 parameters (Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta41, Delta43, Delta). It is too long to put it all here but this is what it looks like:

```
Expr = -(1/2) Re[4.21789*10^-16 ((2.14978*10^-11 E^(-2 I δ) + 
     1.00004*10^-9 (-0.644842 E^(I α) + 0.0000146636 E^(I α - I δ + I δ41))^2 + 
     1000 E^(2 I γ) (0.00750167 E^(I δ43) + 0.99995 (0.00644906 + 
      0.00146621 E^(-I δ + I δ41)))^2 + 1.00125*10^-9 E^(2 I β) (-0.750054 + 
        0.010001 E^(-I δ43) (0.00644906 + 0.00146621 E^(-I δ + I δ41)))^2) 
         (1.216*10^-10 E^(-I δ) + 1.00004*10^-9 (0.644842 E^(-I α) - 
           0.0000146636 E^(-I α - I δ + I δ41)) (-0.000082943 E^(-I α + I δ41) - 
        0.99995 E^(-I α) (0.413249 + 0.0801478 E^(I δ))) - 
     1000 E^(-2 I γ) (0.00750167 E^(I δ43) + 0.99995 (0.00644906 + 
       0.00146621 E^(-I δ + I δ41))) (E^(I δ43) (-0.00355317 + 0.00093234 E^(I δ)) + 
        0.99995 (0.0041327 + 0.000801518 E^(I δ) - 0.00829347 E^(I δ41))) + 
         1.00125*10^-9 E^(-2 I β) (0.750054 - 0.010001 E^(-I δ43) (0.00644906 + 
           0.00146621 E^(-I δ + ........
```

My problem is the following, when I evaluate this expression for some numerical values of the parameters, I do not get the same result whether I use the exponential form or the trigonometric one whereas they are supposed to be exactly the same.

```
Expr /. {α -> 1, β -> 2, γ -> 3, δ43 -> 4, δ41 -> 5, δ -> 6}
```

> 1.68977*10^-38

```
ExpToTrig[Expr] /. {α -> 1, β -> 2, γ -> 3, δ43 -> 4, δ41 -> 5, δ -> 6}
```

> 2.7918*10^-38

Question: How can I get the same result using both forms?

Comment: Rounding errors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, but what is the difference between Expr and ExpToTrig[Expr] regarding the errors ?

Comment: A good answer to this question would show, how to use `Precision` to avoid this from happening.

Comment: @Johu Thanks for the clarification. Do you mean I must increase the numerical precision of all numbers that I put in the code in order to avoid this ?

Comment: @Pon, I recommend you change your question from "why does it happen" (happens because of rounding errors in different analytic forms of the experssion) to "how to avoid it from happening". It should be possible to change the precision of the evaluation locally. After changing the question, it might get opened again. I don't think it is a bad question.

Comment: The second problem is, that we have no way of reproducing your problem. Even if the expression is long, consider making it available to us in some way or find a simpler expression, which has the same problem.